# XP Mode ODBC Connection Problem

Tags: windows-xp, windows

I have just installed XP Mode on our Windows 7 Computer. I need XP Mode because we have a legacy accounting program that doesn't run in Windows 7. The problem we are having is that when I run the accounting program in XP Mode it starts but then reports a connection problem. I understand that is a problem with the ODBC connection. I there any way that I can correct this? I will really appreciate you help....

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're getting? You need to be more specific, and give details about what you've tried as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to installed or configure ODBC on the XP OS.  Any settings you configure in the Windows 7 machine will not copy over to the XP OS.